# How can I convert elements (e.g. integers) of an array to array so that I will gain an extra dimension in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array looking like this:

```
data=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
data=np.array(data)
```

Now I want to convert it to a shape like this:

```
data2=[[[1],[2],[3]],[[4],[5],[6]]]
```

This way I would get an extra dimension. How can I turn data to data2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using reshape?

```
data.reshape(2,3,1)
> array([[[1],[2],[3]],
         [[4],[5],[6]]])
```

Comment: Thanks man. I literally looked for a solution all day. Still wondering where google algorithm went wrong or if my search queries were to complicated.

Comment: If you researches depends on numpy, take a 3 hours workshop (available on youtube) that done at PyCon (like every PyCon last 3 years has an intro for numpy and pandas). Maybe you wouldn't lean everything on this 3 hours, but at least you would know what numpy can and what it can't do. The first thing I did is to open my notes and confirm I think about the correct function.